# Enable button based on user ID

Tags: reactjs, firebase, jsx

I'm trying to enable a button based on the currentUser.uid

```
const handleButton = (imageId) => {
  if (imageId === currentUser.uid) {
    return false;
  } else {
    return true;
  }
};
```

```
<IconButton
  disabled={handleButton(image.id)}
  color="secondary" aria-label="delete image"
  onClick={() => handleDeleteImage(image.id, image.userID, image.name)}
  component="span" >
</IconButton>
```

But all my buttons stay disabled. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Did you check the `currentUser.uid` and `imageId` are  same?

Comment: It would probably be useful to edit the post to include the contents of 'image' that are resulting in this behaviour

Comment: Ahh yep that was it. Image.Id had to be image.userID. I feel stupid

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
const handleButton = (imageId) => {
    if (imageId == currentUser.uid) {
        return false;
    }
    else {
        return true;
    }
}
```